# iOS dismissing a modally presented Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller

I present a Navigation Controller this way:

```
let navController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("myId") as! UINavigationController

self.presentViewController(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

How do I dismiss this `Navigation Controller` using a `Navigation Bar Button` that is set up **from the storyboard**? is it possible?

NOTE: I'm **not** asking the logic of how to dismiss a VC, I am aware of the `protocol/delegate` pattern. Instead I'm asking whether I can put a `"Cancel"` button in the nav bar, and if that button's `IBAction` would be declared inside `Navigation Controller` subclass or in the navcontroller's root view controller

Comment: Why not you are using right bar button with title as "Cancel".

Comment: One way to find out--try it out yourself. ;) Usually though, the Cancel and Done buttons are assigned as the `navigationItem`s of the view controllers that the navigation controller contains.

Comment: I tried but the button isn't showing, I'm clearly doing something wrong or it isn't possible to do it on storyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UINavigationController` does not own the navigation bar button items. Its provided by the view controller pushed in to the stack. You can dismiss the `UINavigationController` from any of the view controller's navigation bar, provided it was presented modally. It is possible to add a `UINavigationBar` in storyboard and have an `IBOutlet` for bar button item that performs dismissal.

Comment: So, if I got it right, I have to add said "Cancel" button to each VC managed by the Nav Controller. I tried doing it in Storyboard but the button won't show, what am I doing wrong?